# External link with dynamic range in sumproduct

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to built a formula in excel in order to have a `SUMPRODUCT` in an external file. I have to "point" `SUMPRODUCT` in a different column every week. Example: during w32 `SUMPRODUCT` points on column `AA`, during w33 it points on column `AB` etc.

This is the working formula with `SUMIFS` and `OFFSET`:

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET('[FEDE.xlsx]Avanzamento WO'!$AM$4;0;WEEKNUM(TODAY())-29;1000);'[FEDE.xlsx]Avanzamento WO'!$K$4:$K$1003;B5)
```

This is the working formula with `SUMPRODUCT` (with static range):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[FEDE.xlsx]Avanzamento WO'!$K$3:$K$10000=B4);'[FEDE.xlsx]Avanzamento WO'!$AP$3:$AP$10000)
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance to everybody

Federico

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. I think you didn't express yourself very well about your real goal here, but I got the feeling your question is just "how to reference a column by a number". If that's the case you could always use `column` or `address` functions or change the cells reference rule to `RC` on `Excel`'s options.

Comment: I want to transform this
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C4=RC[-4]);C10)
in something like this
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C4=RC[-4]);C(WEEKNUM(TODAY()))

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to use your original OFFSET formula? In such case, you can apply either:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Avanzamento WO'!$K$3:$K$1000=B5),OFFSET('Avanzamento WO'!$AM$3:$AM$1000,0,WEEKNUM(TODAY())-29))
```

or (version 2):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('Avanzamento WO'!$K$3:$K$1000=B5),OFFSET('Avanzamento WO'!$AM$3,0,WEEKNUM(TODAY())-29,998))
```

Note that I am using a range that ends in row 1000. `SUMPRODUCT` formula requires all ranges (arrays) to be of the same size. Your original `SUMIFS` formula was ending with row 1,000 while `SUMPRODUCT` approach was ending with 10,000, so I wasn't sure which one was correct. Also your `SUMIFS` was pointing to cell B5 while `SUMPRODUCT` was analysing cell B4.

Results:

[image]

Oh and I am using `,` instead of `;` so you would also need to have it adjusted :)